# telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused

Tags: rhel, telnet

I am using RHEL 6.0 and when i type the given command in terminal

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 6000
```

I am getting output as:

```
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
```

Why is this connection refusing?

Comment: Presumably, because there's nothing running on localhost that's listening on TCP port 6000.

Answer (score 4):

Because there's nothing listening there. If you'd expect an X server to answer, you'll need to tell it to enable TCP (remove the `-nolisten tcp` for instance, or add `-listen tcp` for those that don't listen on TCP by default).

But if you don't need your X server to be accessed directly over the network (other than tunnelled/proxied over `ssh`), it's probably wiser to leave it there.

You can connect to your X server with a Unix domain socket instead. For instance (for `:0`) with:

```
socat - /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

Which would be the equivalent of:

```
socat - tcp:localhost:6000
```

Or (as you're on Linux), with an *abstract* domain socket:

```
socat - abstract:/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
```

Other reasons why you can't talk to your X server would be if it's listening on a different port (6000 is for the `:0` display) or not at that address or the wildcard address, or on a different network protocol (`IPv6` instead of `IPv4`), or if there's a firewall rule rejecting connections there.